# How to transform a Epoch Unix Timestamp in milliseconds to a Date in swift

Tags: swift, date

There's a value representing Unix Epoch timestamp in milliseconds as a `String`:

```
let val = "1492495200000"
```

How to transform this value to **Date** in **swift**?

Comment: What should the output be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this one :

```
let val = 1492495200000;
var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (Double(val) / 1000.0));
print(date);
```

Well your value is time interval in milliseconds. This is reason why you should do division by 1000, before you will do date convert.

Comment: would be nice if you provided an explanation to what you did

Comment: @KirilS. I think it is ok now